# Debugging CSS in Google Chrome

Tags: css, debugging, google-chrome

I am writing some CSS files, but when I make a mistake, Chrome appears to just *silently* ignore the parts that I screw up, and renders the rest.

This makes it annoying to debug since I can't figure out what is going wrong.

So, is there a way to get Chrome to "scream at me in big red letters," so that I can spend less time finding the error and more time fixing it?

Comment: You can use the element inspector in chrome to see the CSS applied to an element and overruled/ignored CSS rules. To open the element inspector you can use f12 or ctrl+shift+j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CSS is not a scripting language, you cant properly debug it. Anyway if you know where it goes wrong you can try to tune it by hand.

Aditionally you've got the w3c validator here: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ which may give you some feedback

Comment: How can you use that if you are developing an app locally. For example, I am using Visual Studio 2013 and run an app by pressing F5.

Answer (score 6):

While you can not "debug" CSS, because it is not a scripting language, you can utilize the Chrome DevTools Elements panel to inspect an element & view the Styles pane on the right. This will give you insights as to the styles being overridden or ignored (line threw). The Styles pane is also useful because of it's ability to LiveEdit the document being inspected, which may help you iron out the issues. If the styles are being overridden, you can then view the Computed Style pane to see the CSS that is actually being utilized to style your document.

To bring up the Chrome DevTools window, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in a Chrome browser tab. (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for a mac)

For more info visit https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index