# HTML footer not working on Github Pages

Tags: html, css

I have a website that is hosted using Github Pages, and I can't seem to get my footer working.  It won't even give any text a background color:

```
h1 {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

So, when I try to code a footer, I am trying to make a footer like the one on the bottom of this page, and it doesn't do any `background-color: #color;`.
I would love to have some help, so here's the HTML and CSS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
                <script src='script.js'></script>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="MyLogo.ico" />

    </head>

    <body>
      <center>
        <img src="A.jpg"></img>
          <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <a href="About/">About</a>
            <a href="Photos/">Photos</a>
            <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
          </div>
    </center>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>

        <div class="footer">

      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Amundson-Aerial-Photography-AAP-881108668736951/">My Facebook page</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>







body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: .3s;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
       background-color: #666666;
}    
    .footer {
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #000000;
       padding: 60px 0px;
       position:fixed;
       left:0px;
       bottom:0px;
       height:50px;
       width:100%;
       background:#999;

    }
```

Comment: Oh, also, `background` will override `background-color`... so remove that

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code you shared above, it is applying a background color, however you had a `background:#999` rule below so it overrid it.

Worth looking into css inheritence if thats something your unsure about, but put simply a rule further down in the same selector statement, or with a more specific selector, that will always override.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

I also used self close tag for your `<img/>`, which is the correct syntax, as an `<img>` tag has no end tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

```css
body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: .3s;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
       background-color: #666666;
}    
    .footer {
       width: 100%;
       padding: 60px 0px;
       position:fixed;
       left:0px;
       bottom:0px;
       height:50px;
       width:100%;

       background-color: #000000;
       background:#999;
       background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
                <script src='script.js'></script>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="MyLogo.ico" />

    </head>

    <body>
      <center>
        <img src="A.jpg" />
          <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <a href="About/">About</a>
            <a href="Photos/">Photos</a>
            <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
          </div>
    </center>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>

        <div class="footer">

      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Amundson-Aerial-Photography-AAP-881108668736951/">My Facebook page</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, still not working.  It works perfectly in the code snippet, but when 
I edit my files in Github, it doesn't work at all.  Maybe using GitHub wrong?

Comment: @IraAmundson 
- try debuging your css ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065229/debugging-css-in-google-chrome) and removing one by one anything not in the working copy

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you can not change background footer, `background-color: #000000;` and `background:#999;` have same function. Delete one.